# Issue with scrollbars in a asp:listbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a list box with multiple values. I need a functionality to move items up/down  using 
`Ctrl+uparrow/Ctrl+downarrow.` I am here by stuck with a issue when the selected item in the `listbox` is out of focus the `scrollbars` do not move correspondingly and the selected item is out of visibility.Any help is greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Demo:  [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Srilatha0406/9EQhR/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#list').on('scroll',function(){$('#list2').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());});
```

OR for both listboxes:

```
$('#list2').on('keyup',function(){$('#list').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());});
$('#list').on('keyup',function(){$('#list2').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());});
```

Comment: This still does work...the selected item still remains out or focus when moved up or down as the scroll bars donot move

Comment: Do you choose item programmaticly and item haven't focus?

Comment: The items in the listbox are added dynamically. There is no restriction of how many items would be in the listbox.The functionality is by using Ctrl+ uparrow/downarrow they should be able to re-order the elements in the listbox.I want the scrollbars to move according as the listitem moves so that the focused item is always visible on the UI.Hope I am clear with my description